# How to test an Ansible role that contains reboot task on CI?

Tags: ansible, github-actions, molecule

I'm looking for a reliable way to test ansible roles on GitHub actions (or any other kind of CI). Unfortunately it contains the following built-in task:

```
- name: Reboot a slow machine
  reboot:
    reboot_timeout: 3600
```

This has caused a lot of trouble for CI. I have the option to launch a docker instance by default:

```
driver:
  name: docker
  image: jrei/systemd-fedora
```

(in molecule.yml format), but ansible wasn't able to reboot it, as no systemd process can be found within the instance

I could also switch the driver to vagrant, which uses a virtual machine. But neither GitHub actions nor any other kind of CI has the capability of running it.

So what's the best practice in this case?

Comment: And simply putting a `when: not ansible_env.CI | d("")` on that task doesn't accomplish your goals?

Comment: It kind of circumvents the problem, so does the tag `molecule_notest` but IMHO it indicates a compromise in test coverage.